# Inserting Pin programmatically to access a private key on a smart card

Tags: .net, pki

Having failed trying to insert the pin code via the `CspParameters` class, this one had [a working solution](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2010/11/22/Setting-the-PIN-of-a-smartcard-programmatically.aspx)

While a bit familiar with KSP and Base CSP architecture in Windows, I haven't got much clue what goes on in there, but it's currently working on all the smart card readers I've tested.

One thing that has me worried though, does -that- solution (or any other way to programmatically insert a pin code) work with a **smart card reader with keypads** ? I have nothing concrete, but common sense would say, that if the person doesn't insert the pin code via keypad, the application would totally be cut off from the smart card (imagine a scenario, where a WPF FAT client has a separate textbox for pin code)?